# Spring 4 TaskScheduler performance issue

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am building a Spring 4 Rest API for a trade automation site.

In service layer a cronjob is dynamically created using Spring *`TaskScheduler.schedule(Runnab‌​le arg0, Date arg1)`* interface which will create a *`Runnable`*, to be executed at the time given as parameter, exactly once. This thread will call another service to access my Hibernate DAO layer and do something in future.

The configuration class and implementation is given below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com.example")    
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {     
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }    
}


@Service
public class TransactionServiceImp implements TransactionService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler; //org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutorService taskService; //My service

    @Transactional
    public myFunction(){

       //some code

       final Long key = //some id value from db
       Date exeTime = //some java.util.Date in future

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {            

            private long id = key;
            public void run() {
                taskService.doSomething(id);
            }
        };
        ScheduledFuture<?> sheduler = scheduler.schedule(runnable, exeTime);

       //some code    
    }    
}
```

This code is working fine and executes the task **at exact time and exactly once**.

By means of eclipse debugging, its found that a new daemon thread is created each time *`scheduler.schedule()`* is called (when processing http requests to spring mvc). My problem is,

> 1. Is my thinking correct that jvm creates new daemon thread on each
>      `scheduler.schedule()` call (Rather than creating thread at the
>      date-time specified) ?
> 2. The created daemon threads are still showing *`Running`* status in
>          Eclipse debug even after the task executed. Will the thread be
>          destroyed or not on finishing *`run()`* method ?
> 3. Else, will it be a performance issue ?

Comment: That depends on which `TaskScheduler` you use. Also you might want to consider an alternative. When a task is scheduled and your JVM crashes the task is gone, if that isn't a problem you might be fine. Else you might want to look at something like quartz.

Comment: I am using `org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler` interface and  `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` implementation. JVM crash and task gone is not a problem as transaction status is stored in db and it will be checked on next startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ThreadPoolTaskScheduler wrapper around [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)(an underlying jdk implementation), threads can be reused from predefined set of worker threads. Each tasks are assigned/processed to  work queue.

> even core threads are initially created and started only when new
>   tasks arrive

Is my thinking correct that jvm creates new daemon thread on each scheduler.schedule() call (Rather than creating thread at the date-time specified) ?

Your are creating thread instance(Runnable) each time, since it accepts runnable, hence your task should be executed or existing worker thread in the queue which may be idle. if max pool size is reached your task will wait.

The created daemon threads are still showing Running status in Eclipse debug even after the task executed. Will the thread be destroyed or not on finishing run() method ?

Java doc says this,

> Execution will end once the scheduler shuts down or the returned
>   ScheduledFuture gets cancelled.

Else, will it be a performance issue ? Maximum optimal number of thread that can be run are limited by cpu cores. So increasing pool size does not, necessarily increase performance

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. On further debugging, its found that I had misunderstood the Daemon threads as `TaskScheduler` threads. But they are not. They are created for each request (obviously in case of servlet). There is only one thread for `TaskScheduler` which keeps running after first call. This single thread manages all tasks added later.  So I think **there wont be any performance issue for above code**, right?

Comment: yes it wont be. And FYI, if you dont specify the pool size it assumed 1.